# RethinkDB: Updating documents

Tags: rethinkdb

This is a longshot, but I was wondering if in rethinkDB, let's say I update a document. Is there a magic function such that, if it is a field that is a string or int, it just updates it, but if the value of the field is an array, it appends it to the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you'd need to use `.branch` and branch on the type.  Something like `.update(function(row) { return {field: r.branch(row('field').typeOf().eq('ARRAY'), row('field').add([el]), el)}; })`

Comment: Dumb question, but does row('field') work for all fields or do I have to put it in there?

Comment: You need to replace `field` in that example with the specific field you're updating.

Answer (score 2):

There is a magic function that does something similar. `.forEach` has the undocumented behaviour of adding numbers, combining arrays and drops strings:

```
>>> r.expr([{a:1, b:[2], c:"3"}, {a:2, b:[4], c:"6"}]).forEach(r.row)
{"a": 3, "b": [2,4], "c": "3"}
```

Comment: What happens to strings? Do they get added?